# Is it correct to say "In order to overcome this loss"?

Tags: vocabulary

I am looking for a word that I can use in a situation where I would like to say:

- In order to "overcome" the loss, we have to ... .

I know somehow that the word "overcome" is not correct to use here.

I tried "In order to achieve a lower loss, we have to ..."

Comment: In order to avoid the loss...

Comment: I would use the verb overcome to talk a victory over adversity, something/one. Try- Inorder to make the loss.

Comment: If the loss has already happened and you're trying to carry on in spite of it, "overcome" would work. However, if you're trying to prevent the loss from happening in the first place, "prevent" or "avoid" would work better.

Comment: Assuming the remedial action is only expected to "achieve a lower loss" (rather that eliminate losses completely), you might consider *"In order to **reduce** the loss..."* as more precise phrasing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nicole's comment is correct, particularly if *loss* refers to an emotionally trying event:

> If the loss has already happened and you're trying to carry on in spite of it, "overcome" would work. However, if you're trying to prevent the loss from happening in the first place, "prevent" or "avoid" would work better. –  [Nicole](/users/94567/nicole) 2014-12-12 16:43:23Z

Both *prevent* and *avoid* are good alternatives to *overcome* if the loss has not yet happened and is not an emotional event.

Note, *in order to* is verbose; typically, *in order* adds nothing and can be dropped.

Answer (score 4):

If the loss has already happened, it can still be "mitigated".

Mitigation of loss (steps taken to minimise a loss after a breach of duty has already occurred) is a well recognised feature of English common law.

Answer (score 3):

I'd say it depends on context. Your example suggests it's a business one. If so, either *minimize* or *offset* would be suitable.

*Offset* as a verb is not jargon. Oxford defines it as "[to] counteract (something) by having an equal and opposite force or effect." If that's your intention, to cancel out the effects of the loss, then it's a good choice. If you hope only to reduce the worst effects of the loss, I'd go with *minimize*. (Or minim*ise* in the UK and some other countries.)

As noted, *in order* is not needed here.

Answer (score 2):

Suitable words are ***minimize***, ***reduce***, or ***cut** our losses*.  The latter is particularly common to describe taking a small loss now to avoid the possibility of an even greater loss in the future.